# How to make the header image darker

Tags: css, header, background-image

I'm new to html and currently trying to toggle the brightness of the background to 0.5, but somehow the text gets affected as well.
Has anyone here any solution for this?

```
jsfiddle.net/dg3h4k4j/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi what is happening is that your `.header` css class is being applied to your h1 element. One way to fix this is to put your header and h1 tag in separate divs the over lap them.

Like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
    </div>   
    <div class="title">
        <h1>BFIT6A</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add this to your css:

```
.title{
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Here is a full [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thedos/gyb2zhn4/) . I hope this helps you good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much !! Ive written sth. about position:absolute; but i didnt knew that i also had to add top: 0px.

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to mark this as the answer if it worked.

Comment: hey man, now i got the problem that i cant use the navbar properly. I can only hover over one part.

Comment: This is because the h1 tag is overlapping the nav bar to fix this change the line height in your csss for the h1 tag and update your title css. I have updated my jsFiddle so you can see what I mean.